# Yet another Java generics "incompatible types" compilation error

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I was writing some code and came across a `incompatible types` compilation error.
This is what I have:

```
public interface Expression<T> {
    int getArity();
    T evaluate();
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Value<T> implements Expression<T> {
    @Override
    public final int getArity() { return 0; }
}
```

---

```
public final class Constant<T> extends Value<T> {
    private final T value;

    /** Parameter constructor of objects of class Constant. */
    public Constant(T val) {
        value = val;
    }

    /** Copy constructor of objects of class Constant. */
    private Constant(Constant instance) {
        value = instance.evaluate();    // Error here.
    }

    @Override
    public T evaluate() { return value; }
}
```

I thought I wasn't declaring generics correctly when using inheritance, so I checked [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), in which they write

```
interface PayloadList<E,P> extends List<E>
```

The above declaration uses the same generic type `E`, which is what I want to accomplish in my example. It seems to be assuming that the `T` from `Constant<T>` is different from the one from `Value<T>`. Otherwise it should be able to *merge* both `T` and see it's the same type.
How can I correctly implement what I'm trying to achieve?

(*Ie, a constant of something is a value of something, which is an expression of the same something*)

Comment: I suspect you want `private Constant(Constant<T> instance) {` instead...

Comment: ^^ `Constant` != `Constant<T>` - When you don't specify the generic it's going to be `Constant<Object>`

Comment: I surely was convinced that it must have been something small escaping my eyes. I tried it, and it now compiles, with `unsafe operations` warning.

Comment: Indeed, figured it out now. @OliCharlesworth if you want to post that as an answer, I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `instance` variable is defined as `Constant instance;`

**If you don't specify your generic on your variable, the generic type will automatically be `Object`**, and the type `Object` is different from `T`.

You have to use

```
private Constant(Constant<T> instance)
```

instead of

```
private Constant(Constant instance)
```

because this would be the same as `private Constant(Constant<Object> instance)`